# Firebase emulator loses connection after exception is thrown

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am getting:
`ConnectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3002` after exception is thrown in the firebase function. Is this expected behaviour ?.

Emulators are started with this command
`firebase emulators:start --non-interactive`

Usually when server throws an exception it just returns 500 status error. But with the emulator i can not make any subsequent requests to it. Am i supposed to handle errors in some way and will this happen in production if unhandled error occurs.

Thank you and best regards

Comment: Can you describe your setup? How are you connecting to the Auth Emulator (are you manually setting up the environment variable?) Also check with this [Link1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4741), [Link2](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5367#issuecomment-1367506613), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73179684/18265702) and [Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75466635/18265702).

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni Thanks for fast reply issue was with my elastic search container not running but why would emulator break for subsequent requests ?

Comment: Can you explain about your infrastructure? Also share minimal replicating steps and logs?